# Allow letters, digits and certain characters and delete the rest

Tags: php

when user submit a form input text

i want it just to allow a-z 0-9 and -_ just this numbers digits and -_

how do i check the input and make it only this inputs allows and delete the rest

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/", '', $input);
```

Comment: No need to escape the -, as it's the last item in the list. No harm done, though. You could also specify just a-z or A-Z and use the "i" flag.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Actually, the first version of that answer the - was not escaped. Then I doubted myself and went back to add without testing. :)  Forgot about the "i" flag. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate($value){
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*$/", $value) !== 0;
}
```

If the return value is false then you have invalid characters, if it true, everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z\_\-]/i", "", $_POST["myfield"]);
```

Use regexp.